# Infinite issues python versions macOS and modules

Tags: python, python-module, pyenv

I have been having many issues with my python on macOS
(Im a beginner)
I want to use modules but every time I install something it says that the module doesn't exist even though its already installed I think it might be cause of the many versions of Python

python3 -- version says python 3.10.8   pip3 --version says python 3.9 (system)  I have python 3.11.1 it does not work. In vscode I want to use packages I install them it says they don't exist. I change my VS-code python to all the different versions they still say they dont exist. I install the packages it says they already exist

```
from fastapi import FastAPI       (, Request)
```

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'
```

I have tried using pyenv to manage versions and it says everything is on 3.11.1 but it doesn't change anything i have tried to remove the other versions of python but has been unsuccessful

Comment: The pip installer and everything auto goes to the 3,9 versions but when I check the installed modules its not there

Comment: To solve your immediate problem you can use explicit versions of pip. `pip3.11` to install packages for use with `python3.11`. `pip3.10` for `python3.10` etc.. At some point you will want to clean up your installation. Also, you'll want to become familiar with `virtualenv`.

Comment: You can take a look at [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or learn to maintain `venv`.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal python, your vs-code terminal python and your project interpreter python could be diverse depends on how you install python.

To keep it simple, keep them watch same python.

On your terminal, go to your project root directory.

Type,
`python -m virtualenv .venv`
Virtualenv has created named '.venv'.

On terminal type `source .venv/bin/activate` to activate created python.
Now, your terminal python is same as your `.venv`.
Install all your dependency by hitting pip install -r requirements.txt

On your IDE, vs-code, set python interpreter to your `~/project/path/.venv/bin/python`.

Now Every python see same python.